# Declaring array and printing [BUG?]

Tags: c++, arrays, codeblocks, element

this might be a noob question, but still i am so confused why this happens.
So this code works just fine:

```
int *m,g;
    g=1;
    m[0]=1;
    cout<<m[0];
```

and this one reports error:

```
int *m;
    m[0]=1;
    cout<<m[0];
```

Could this be a bug?

Comment: Yes it is a bug in your code. This is Undefined behavior because the pointer has not been initialized.

Comment: Could you be more specific, why it works in first case?

Comment: `int* m;` then `m[0]=1` is a bug. so is any other access to `m[any index]`

Comment: ***why it works in first case?*** Unfortunately undefined behavior sometimes returns the result you expect. However you can't count on it at all it may fail on a different computer or the same computer even if you change an unrelated line in your program.

Comment: thanks for helping

Comment: `int *m` is a pointer to a `int`. It is not an array of integers as you seem to believe.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an uninitialized array and you try to access it  causing you an undefined behaviour

according to the standard

> If no initializer is specified for an object, the object is
>   default-initialized. When storage for an object with automatic or
>   dynamic storage duration is obtained, the object has an indeterminate
>   value, and if no initialization is performed for the object, that
>   object retains an indeterminate value until that value is replaced ...
>   If an indeterminate value is produced by an evaluation, the behavior
>   is undefined

you should initialized like this before

```
int *m=new int[size_you_want_give_to]
```

eg

```
int *m=new int[5]; // array of 5 elements
```

Comment: but why it does work in first case? In the second case i just removed g=1 and it doesn't work

Comment: thats what undefined behavior means it may work it may not it may does something else inside you computer & that's why it's too dangerous to have in your code

Comment: you can read more about it in here : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/undefined-behavior-c-cpp/